# Create a custom PrincipalPermission for ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to build a web application with form authentications and I have my own roles and permissions for each user (Add, Update, Delete, View). PrincipalPermission is very useful in denying any user without permissions to from running a specific method, but I don't want to use a membership — I have my own permissions and roles.

How I can create my own PrincipalPermission to check my custom privileges? I think it must be like this `[CustomPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,UserPrivilege=currentUser.x)]`
Where `currentUser.x` is bool to indicate if user have to access this method.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: You want to restrict access to users with a specific SecurityAction? What is the user priviledge for?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use membership provider to integrate with .net authentication and authorization.

You can control access to your code programmatically or using attributes. .Net will validate the user based on the current Principal.

How the Principal is filled is up to you. You could user membershipProvider or your own scheme.

The default Principal has a username and a set of roles. If don't have any special need you could just use that.

Check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649350.aspx#secnetch03_designauthstrategy

Comment: so How I can add my own Roles without using .Net Membership ?

Comment: I'm sorry I think I misread your post. I somehow read you were trying to use MembershipProvider.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Principal .net authentication for your web application with some changes in FormAuthentication very easy:
please read [This project](http://codefirstmvc3.codeplex.com/)

Comment: This Code is for MVC but I need a normal ASP.Net, I have no idea about MVC, can you help ?